# Determine time since last user activity in Android

Tags: android, power-management

How do you discover when, in the future, the device is expected to sleep?

Or, at least, when the last user activity was?

Comment: To find out when the last user activity was, see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7743976/android-activity-manager/7744354#7744354

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do you discover when, in the future, the device is expected to sleep?

You don't. There is no API for this. The device will go to sleep after the user-specified timeout has elapsed *and* after all outstanding `WakeLocks` are released. It is impossible to predict when the device will go to sleep, since the OS has no idea when those `WakeLocks` will be released.