# Android activity manager

Tags: android

I guess, I have a generic logic problem. I want to logout a user after 15 if there is no activity. How do I find any "activity" in android. How should I go about it...

Experts please help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to invest a little thought into exactly what your requirements are here, but from what I can tell, you want to keep track of the user interactions and if a time limit expires since the last interaction, perform some action, in your case logging them out of your application.

Firstly, you'll need some place that you can track when the last interaction occured, since you'll want this to be application wide you could use a [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) to hold this, or [override the Application](http://www.jameselsey.co.uk/blogs/techblog/android-implementing-global-state-share-data-between-activities-and-across-your-application/) class, either way should do.

Next, you'll need to start tracking user interactions. From your activities, you can override the [onUserInteraction](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onUserInteraction%28%29) method, this gets invoked anytime the user interacts with the application such as key event. Each time you hit this method, update your singleton and let it know something has happened, with a timestamp.

Finally, you'll need some kind of looping check to constantly check if anything has happened recently. Theres various was of doing this, you could have a continuous loop that compares current timestamp to the last recorded event, a bit of draft code :

```
while(true)
{
   if (timeLastEventRecorded < (now - 15))
   {
      //nothing has happened in 15 minutes, so take corrective action
   }
}
```

Presumably you'll already have some code in your application that takes care of logouts, such as when the user clicks "logout", you should just be able to invoke that in the sample above.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You should have all activities inherit from a parent activity that overrides [onUserInteraction()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onUserInteraction%28%29). In that callback you should reset a static app wide timer that will perform your logout code when the time reaches the end.